# Relation between ordinal numbers and ordinal bases in PE-files

Tags: windows, x86, portable-executable

> Relation between ordinal numbers and ordinal bases in PE-files.

Doing some PE-analysis, I cannot recognize what the PE-documentation says in practice:

> Thus, when the export name pointer table is searched and a matching
>   string is foundat position i, the algorithm for finding the symbol’s
>   address is:

```
i = Search_ExportNamePointerTable (ExportName);
ordinal = ExportOrdinalTable [i];
SymbolRVA = ExportAddressTable [ordinal - OrdinalBase];
```

Having located the ordinal `x` for e.g. `ExitProcess` and verified to ordinal base to be `0x01`, the RVA for `ExitProcess` is found at position `x` within the export address table, and not at position `x - 1` as specified by the documentation.

Indeed, to look up the RVA for a function, I compute `export_address_base + ordinal * 0x04`, and not the advertised `export_address_base + (ordinal - 1) * 0x04`

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you include a quote where `xport_address_base + (ordinal - 1) * 0x04` is advertised?

Comment: The algorithm I quote is from the PE-documentation, the OrdinalBase is 1, and the field size is 0x04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can \`kernel32.dll\` export an ordinal of 0, when its \`OrdinalBase\` field is set to 1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39996742/how-can-kernel32-dll-export-an-ordinal-of-0-when-its-ordinalbase-field-is-s)